# Can Continuous Integration Services build Linux packages natively?

Tags: c++, linux, travis-ci, rpmbuild

CI services like TravisCI automatically build and test applications from source control.  I'm new to C++ and linux, but it seems like wrapping compiled linux applications into .deb and .rpm packages for various linux distros would also be a very common need for a build pipeline.  I googled for a few hours, and can't find any documentation or reference to streamlined mechanism in Travis or elsewhere which makes this easy.  Perhaps C++ developers are accustomed to doing this kind of thing themselves and so they just script it in the build.

However, when trying to setup the pipeline for a new team and project with multiple packages, each targeting 5+ distros and wanting to test the resulting packages, it's a perfect candidate for a CI pipeline.  We want to deploy the packages on Bintray where we have several RPM and DEB repositories prepared to receive packages for the various distros.  However, we can find no trace of a widely-used solution which takes a compiled artifact and package definition, and then rolls them up and deploys them to these repos.

Does anyone have an easy-to-use and automated solution for building linux packages as they're built in Travis before being deployed to a repository?

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CPack for that - it allows you write a general package description and build a rpm, deb and msi from the description.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be easy to find because it's trivial once you have the RPM specfiles set up, which is where 95% of the problems show up. ;)

I have Jenkins spin up Docker containers for each target OS (CentOS 6, 7, Fedora 25) and build the RPMs. It's no different than any other "shell script" build step, except instead of calling `make`, it calls `rpmbuild`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand how things can seem trivial after we work through them.  However, objectively speaking, it's far from trivial to setup a complete process as described.  The scenario you described is simply very different.  You mention about 50% of the tasks required in the original post. You describe using Jenkins which is a CI application and not a CI service like Travis, which means it has to be hosted and maintained on a VM.  You also don't mention testing the packages.  Again, what we're looking for is just different.  We're now exploring CPack, which is promising.

Comment: The point of my response is that I don't think there is going to be anything Jenkins- or Travis-specific in creating the RPMs once you have the basic RPM building working.